# How to calculate a root in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've made a four function calculator in Visual Basic, and it also has square root. However, I was looking to improve on it so that the user can input cube roots, fourth roots, fifth roots, etc. How might I do this? I guess I'm kind of asking for a formula to calculate it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty simple example showing you how to do it:

```
Dim number As Double = Double.Parse(txtNumber.Text)
Dim root As Double = Double.Parse(txtRoot.Text)

' Calculate the root.
Dim result As Double = Math.Pow(number, 1 / root)
txtResult.Text = result.ToString()

' Check the result.
Dim check As Double = Math.Pow(result, root)
txtCheck.Text = check.ToString()
```

And the link (back by popular demand):
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_find_nth_root.html

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Once the link dies (it happens) your answer is suddenly useless

Comment: This example is lacking attribution. You need the example *and* the link. ;)